# Связка Website и Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, api

Я начинающий и сейчас активно изучаю ЯП - Python, а помимо этого начал ещё для понимания html5, css3 - т. к. всё же есть понимание, что python - это больше web-бэкенд, если я правильно выражаюсь.
В ходе теории появился важный вопрос, т. к. для улучшения навыков и практики, хочется попробовать реализовать что-то своими руками.
Данный вопрос хочу прояснить у знающих людей, чтобы узнать в каком направлении двигаться, что необходимо прочесть...
**Цель** сделать на Python алгоритм игрового слота *естественно о глобальном слотовом механизме речи не идёт* создать website с простенькой анимацией движения картинок и заставить Python взаимодействовать с сайтом.
Я понимаю, что для анимации будет необходим JS, у меня вопрос больше в другом: я плохо пониманию идею связывания двух **кодов** если так можно выразиться. Точнее механику, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку на сайте и как запрос попадет в алгоритм Python откуда возвращается с ответом для реакции веб-сайта.
В своих поисках я наткнулся на технологию API. Т. к. изучаю самостоятельно, очень прошу поддержки - подскажите, дайте совет правильно ли я двигаюсь и реализуема ли данная затея (я понимаю, что можно сделать что угодно и с любыми костылями, речь больше о том насколько это сложно будет, что лучше отказаться от такого pet-проекта или в принципе самостоятельно изучить можно).
Язык не хотелось бы менять - про SQL тоже знаю, есть понимание.
Буду благодарен ответам

Comment: Если простой вариант. Обратите внимание на Flask.

Answer (score 1):

API: Вы можете создать API на Python с использованием фреймворков, таких как Flask или Django. Это позволит веб-сайту отправлять запросы к вашему Python-коду и получать ответы.

AJAX или Fetch API: Используйте JavaScript для отправки асинхронных запросов (AJAX или Fetch) к вашему API на Python. Это позволит взаимодействовать с сервером без перезагрузки страницы.

Анимация: Для анимации элементов на веб-сайте вы можете использовать JavaScript и библиотеки, такие как jQuery или более современные CSS анимации и библиотеки, например, GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP).

Ну и конечно тестирование.

Так же продолжайте изучать HTML, CSS, JavaScript, python.